# How can I merge these faces more efficiently?

Tags: modeling, faces

I'm trying to get a flat outside ring on this modified sphere for a 3d printing project. Currently I'm selected 3 faces at a time and then `Delete (x)` > `Dissolve Faces (s)`. I don't mind the manual process but I would like to evolve my process for future use.

[image: selecting faces on an oblong sphere]

I'm trying to flatten this new faces to have a flat outer ring similar to an ibuprofen pill.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Either follow Shady Puck's technique or simply use *Collapse Edge Loops* operator

In *Edge Selection* mode use by default <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Select</kbd> to select a full edge loop, then press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Edge Loops*

[image: Collapse Edge Loops]

Comment: Ok, wow. That's really good! Def a +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

Luckily, there is an easy solution that solves both problems at once.

Key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select one of the three edge loops. Key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select the other two. You should have something that looks like the following.

[image]

Key <kbd>X</kbd> to open the *Delete* menu and select *Faces*.

[image]

This should leave you with something like the following.

[image]

Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd>, or switch to *Vertex Select Mode* manually at the bottom of the *3D Viewport*.

[image] --> [image]

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> again to select the edge loops on each side of the newly created gap.

[image]

Key <kbd>W</kbd> to open the *Specials* menu and select *Bridge Edge Loops*.

[image]

Ta-da!

[image]

Comment: "grow selection" (ctrl num+) is your friend here, too, and box select from an orthogonal view might be even easier. I guess grow selection makes it the easiest to keep symmetry.